# Convert time (date type) to numeric in proc SQL (SAS)

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a datetime variable (x= '19NOV2021: 10:00:00') which is a date type. I am trying to just get the hour and convert it to numeric. In this case, just 10.

```
proc sql;
create table abc as
select timepart(x) as x format=time2.
```

The above outputs 10 as a date type. I use the below to try to convert it to numeric but get 3 (numeric type) as my output:

```
proc sql;
create table def as
select input(put(x,best.),8.) as x
```

How can I convert the time to a numeric and get 10 as my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hour()`.

`timepart()` returns a SAS time as the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight. You can use `hour(timepart(x))`, but it's not necessary since `hour` works on both datetimes and times.